# NotSerializableException: Not sure what the reason is

Tags: java, android, serialization

Here is part of code I think is relevant for this question.

```
//Enveloping class
public class BackupSMS implements Serializable{

transient Cursor cursor;
String vfile;
transient Context mContext;
private final String TAG = "BackupSMS";
SMSBackup smsBackup;
transient FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream;

public BackupSMS(Context context, String _vfile) {
    mContext = context;
    vfile = _vfile;
    smsBackup = new SMSBackup();
}
```

Inner classes:

```
public class SMSBackup implements Serializable{
public ArrayList<SMSObject> SMSList;
public SMSBackup() {
    SMSList = new ArrayList<SMSObject>();
}
}

public class SMSObject implements Serializable{
private String id;
private String addr;
private String msg;
.... (more private strings and getter setter methods for them)
}

//method of enveloping class.
public void writeSMSList(){
......
    mFileOutputStream =  mContext.openFileOutput(vfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(mFileOutputStream);
    //smsBackup is an object of SMSBackup class created earlier.
oos.writeObject( smsBackup );
oos.close();
.......
}
```

I don't seem to find any unserializable object in the picture. Any advice as what is going wrong will help.

EDIT: I didn't look close enough at the stack trace. Below is the stack trace I obtained but it is still not taking me any closer to a solution. Any suggestions?

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
```

.... and many more such lines.

Comment: The reason appears in the message. It names a class that isn't serializable. There's nothing to be unsure about.

Comment: Let the problematic class `implements Seializable`.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun - That is only part of the solution ....

Comment: you have not pasted the error that you are getting

Comment: "These are inner classes of some other class." - then serializing them will have to serialize the instance of their containing class too. Is the containing class serializable?

Comment: Yes Ian, I tried that too and made certain fields I suspected as transient but the problem persists. I have added that information in question now.

Comment: Or if they don't actually need to be _inner_ classes (i.e. they don't refer to their containing instance and it would make sense for an instance of the nested class to exist independently of the outer one) then make them `static` classes instead of inner ones.

Comment: What part of 'java.io.NotSerializableException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner' don't  you understand?

Comment: @EJP - Some things which may be obvious to you may not be obvious to me. I have just started working on android (and even Java) and I have realized that there are a lot of things I don't know. That is precisely the reason I am asking the question here. 

As to your question, "ContentResolver" part of that line is what I am not understanding. I am not able to see the reason for the code to reach contentResolver.

Comment: Then that's what you should be asking about, isn't it? Instead of just 'not sure what the reason is'. You didn't give the least indication of how far you'd got in your thinking. You can't expect SO to read your mind. You didn't even post the relevant part of the exception message until prompted, which leads to the conclusion that you hadn't even seen it, let alone understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's nothing in the nested classes that refers directly to their containing instance (e.g. by accessing a non-static field or calling a non-static method of the containing class) then they probably don't need to be inner classes at all. If you mark the classes as `static` then they won't hold a reference to the container instance and therefore won't try to serialize the entire object graph.

Comment: Well that worked Ian. Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I was not aware of the fact that nested classes hold reference to container class.

Comment: @pareshnakhe _inner_ classes do, _static nested_ classes don't. [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) does a good job of explaining the differences. P.S. if my answer solved your problem you should consider marking it as _accepted_ using the tick mark on the left.